# `configure.ac` file giving errors

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, autotools, automake

I am creating a toy example for learning autotools . I created the following files . 
`configure.ac`

```
AC_INIT([hello], [0.01])

# safety check -list a source file that wouldn't be in other directories :                                                          
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([hello.c])

# Put configuration results here so that we can easily #include them                                                                
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Put autotools aux files in a subdir . so they don't clutter top dir :                                                             
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])

# Enable "automake" to simplify creating makefiles :                                                                                
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 -Wall -Werror]
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

#look for a C compiler :                                                                                                            
AC_PROG_CC

# Do final output                                                                                                                   
AC_OUTPUT
```

and a `Makefile.am` :

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

and `hello.c` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
   printf("hello world!\n") ;
   return 0 ; 
}
```

Then I did a `autoreconf -i` in the terminal but I am getting the following :

```
configure.ac:1: error: m4_init: unbalanced m4_divert_push:
configure.ac:17: m4_divert_push: GROW
configure.ac:1: m4_divert: BODY
../../lib/autoconf/c.m4:448: AC_PROG_CC is expanded from...
configure.ac:1: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

What are these errors , how can I fix them ?

Comment: all these files are in a folder named `hello`

Comment: Crossposted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118556/configure-ac-file-giving-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 -Wall -Werror]
```

is missing a `)`. Not sure if that was a `typo`.